# If $E$ is a field and $g(x)\in E[x]$ is a polynomial, then there exists a field $F\supseteq E$ and $a\in F$ such that $g(a)=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show that if $E$ is a field and $g(x)\in E[x]$ is a polynomial, then there exists a field $F\supseteq E$ and $a\in F$ such that $g(a)=0$? Sorry, I am new to algebra. Thanks if you are willing to provide me with some ideas.

Comment: Hint: Take the polynomial $x^2-2$ and then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is required field. Which is the extension of  $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: You may assume $g$ is irreducible, otherwise replace it with one of its irreducible factors. Then the quotient ring $E[x]/(g)$ is a field, and you can naturally think of it as an extension of $E$, under the embedding $a\to a+(g)$ for $a\in E$. Then show that the coset $x+(g)$ is a root of $g$.

Comment: Some sources call $F$ *a rupture field*. I don't like the term myself, and I think it is not standard. But it works as a buzzword, and points at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupture_field).

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kronecker’s_Theorem

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality suppose that $g$ is irreducible. Let $F:=E[X]/(g)$, where $(g)$ is the ideal generated by $g$ in $E[X]$. For $f\in E[X]$ we will denote by $\widehat{f}$ the class of $f$ modulo $(g)$. Since $g$ is irreducible and $E[X]$ is a PID, $(g)$ is a maximal ideal and hence, $F$ is a field. Let $\phi : E \rightarrow F$, $\phi(a) = \widehat{a}$. Note that $\phi$ is a field morphism (so, in particular, it is injective). Then, we can see $E$ as a subfield of $F$, using the isomorphism $E\cong \phi(E)$. Let $x$ be the class of $X$ modulo $(g)$, i.e. $x = \widehat{X}$. Then $g(x) = g(\widehat{X}) = \widehat{g(X)} = 0$. Thus, $x$ is a root of $g$.